# ocaml type clarification (beginner)

Tags: types, ocaml

I have this declaration

```
type 'a dict = string -> 'a option
val empty : unit -> 'a dict
val insert : 'a dict -> string * 'a -> 'a dict
```

following this declaration, how can I write `empty` ? `empty ()` just returns an empty dictionary.

Comment: This is such a fun question for homework, I'm pretty jealous of you tbh :-D

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to short-circuit the part where you figure things out for yourself. Here are hints.

1. A dictionary has the type `string -> 'a option`. I.e., it's a function that returns what you're looking for in the dictionary or `None` if the string isn't associated with a value in the dictionary. Seems like an empty dictionary is one where no string is associated with anything, so the function would always return the same result. It's not so hard to write a function that always returns the same thing.
2. Your code is returning the value (of type `'a`) but it's supposed to return something of type `'a option`. Otherwise it's great code, you are grasping the point of it (IMHO).